# Complicated story identification from book cover

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, cover-art, powers

I really want to find this book again. I had it back in the seventies, the story was complex, surreal, competing realities type.

The cover showed one figure (I think), anyway, their neck was a platform, their head consisted of two small humanoid figures dancing on that platform.

There were I believe, 7 entities in this "station" which was outside of normal reality. And each one completely controlled reality with their section of the station and whatever part of the outside they could manage.

There was also the sense of hypothesis exploding sequences where each time you think you have what is happening figured out, everything changes. Like in The Magus, and/or The Illuminatus Trilogy.

Each one of these principal characters maintained their "bodies" in whatever manner they chose. The cover figure, whose head was the two small dancing figures on his platform like neck, was one of the principal characters.

The whole effect was so bizarre that I think if anybody else has this book or remembers it's name or author or anything, I will be able to trace it down.

Comment: I've never seen such a cover for it, but as a wild guess, "Creatures of Light and Darkness" ?? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatures_of_Light_and_Darkness

Comment: @OrganicMarble a cursory search for images shows no cover matching the description.

Comment: As I commented.

Comment: Not the Zelazny 'C of A & D' that I have seen.

Comment: It's not "C of L & D" - I know that story well.

Comment: Fritz Leiber's "The Big Time" has a group of people outside of reality, although they do not have the complete control over their environment so I suspect it's not the one you are looking for.

Comment: It's not Creatures of Light and Darkness, though that is a wonderful book too.

I will check out the Fritz Leiber's "The Big Time" as I am not familiar with that one.

I still hope to run across somebody else who remembers it. The cover was so exotic and striking. Like so many of my books, I let someone else read it and never saw it again. By the time I realized that, I didn't remember who I lent it to, and they doubtless had forgotten as well.

Anyway thanks for the suggestions. I am still hopeful.

Comment: A Toy for Juliette by Bloch or Prowler in the City at the Edge of the World by Ellison in Dangerous Visions?  A couple of common points but some difference too

Comment: Annoying I can picture the book.  I just can't remember more.

Comment: I can't find a decent plot summary and the cover doesn't QUITE match (the two figures aren't dancing on the cover, and that figure isn't alone), but the cover for Nightchild by Scott Baker does prominantly feature a creature that looks like a human with a platform for a neck and two humans on the platform (Each holding an eyeball).

Comment: I will have to look at all these, and it seems a bit more hopeful now.

Comment: I'll have to check the RA Lafferty stuff out. It sounds Promising, and it's the only real lead that I've gotten. The "toad with a jewel in its head" thing does sound familiar, so I probably have read that story as well. Whether it relates to the other, I'll have to reRead to tell.

Comment: Someone suggested that I provide a picture of the cover. Which is weird, because I don't have the cover. If I did, I would at least know the title and the author, in which case I could easily replace the book. Which would be lovely. It's just a vivid memory of the image.

Comment: Anyway we're only going off memory hear. A fairly clear memory of the cover and a vagueish memory of the story.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds a bit like Fourth Mansions by RA Lafferty - does the idea of a toad with a jewel in its head and a character who has to soak his head in a bucket ring any bells?  It certainly sounds like it might be a Lafferty story, even if not Fourth Mansions itself.

Comment: You could include a picture of cover or a link to a Wikipedia/something else page.

Comment: It's the content that's vaguely familiar, not the cover.  But these books came out in multiple issues and multiple cover designs.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?7649

Comment: @ClaireJordan  -  it's just that OP described a cover, I thought you might save him the trouble of verifying your answer if you put a cover in it.

Comment: I'll have to check the RA Lafferty stuff out. It sounds Promising, and it's the only real lead that I've gotten.